# Travis CI couldn't install openjdk11

Tags: maven, travis-ci, openjdk-11

I have a problem with installing openjdk11 in Travis CI.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Installing openjdk11
$ export JAVA_HOME=~/openjdk11
$ export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
$ ~/bin/install-jdk.sh --target "/home/travis/openjdk11" --workspace "/home/travis/.cache/install-jdk" --feature "11" --license "GPL" --cacerts
install-jdk.sh 2019-04-18
The command "~/bin/install-jdk.sh --target "/home/travis/openjdk11" --workspace "/home/travis/.cache/install-jdk" --feature "11" --license "GPL" --cacerts" failed and exited with 51 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

`.travis.yml` file:

```yaml
language: java
jdk: openjdk11
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.m2/repository"
```

Comment: Could be a new bug on the side of Travis. I have the same issue for a build that worked yesterday.

Comment: Same. I have two jobs failing repeatedly with 51. I've reported it.

Comment: I had the same issue with openjdk 10 and 11. It's fixed now, without doing anything myself :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid this problem, try something like this in your `.travis.yml` configuration file:

```
language: java
dist: xenial
sudo: required

jdk:
  - openjdk11
```

Comment: Worked. `sudo` part is not required.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be an TLS certificate error of `download.java.net`.
Current TLS certificate exposed by `download.java.net` is invalid: it's for `download.oracle.com`.

The 51 return code was returned by the `curl` download command.

You can download the `install-jdk.sh` script :

```sh
curl -o /tmp/install-jdk.sh -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sormuras/bach/master/install-jdk.sh
```

Then run it:

```sh
bash -x /tmp/install-jdk.sh --target "/home/travis/openjdk11" --workspace "/home/travis/.cache/install-jdk" --feature "11" --license "GPL" --cacerts
```

Failing command is:

```sh
curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

with a 51 return code

Comment: Download URL has been fixed : https://github.com/sormuras/bach/commit/db42afccd2c40c903ddf73156f304c2276517c6c#diff-08dca971d5e4fbd0624e7bf955f5adb1. 

`download.oracle.com` is used instead of `download.java.net`

Answer (score 1):

Probably Oracle has to fix their TLS certificate or Travis has to fix it somehow on their end.

In the meantime, we had some luck by adding `dist: xenial` to our Travis configuration, see: https://travis-ci.community/t/install-of-openjdk11-is-failing-again/3061/16

Another solution seems to be to add `oraclejdk11` to the `jdk` list in the Travis configuration.

I wouldn't particularly say that these are actual solutions but mere workarounds for the time being.